# Can't Kill running Mongo (pid XXX)

Tags: meteor

Fairly new to Meteor, however I am having some issues stopping my meteor application and restarting it.

The error I am running into is this:

```
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                                            throw(ex);
                                                  ^
Error: Can't kill running mongo (pid 172).
at /tools/runners/run-mongo.js:310:11
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at findMongoAndKillItDead (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:283:5)
at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:400:7)
at launchMongo (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:656:7)
at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:756:19)
at [object Object]._.extend.start (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:714:10)
```

I tried to do kill -9 on the PID but that does not work, meteor reset did not solve the solution as well. I even went as far as to remove the /root/.meteor directory and the [appname] as well and started over again but the lock is still there.

Is there way around this? I was surprise as there was not really a meteor command to just stop meteor running and gracefully shut down.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A ctrl+C from the shell where meteor is running is enough for close, it seems strange that kill -9 doesn't work with meteor.

However if this is your production application consider to use [mup](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) package from Aronuda to deploy your app it offers commands to deploy, start/stop/restart application and show logs.